# Open website using Android Webview

Tags: webview

I have a custom Rom on my phone and I didn't install Google Chrome; I'm using Firefox instead.
However, once in a blue moon there's a site that complains that it doesn't work with Firefox and suggests using Chrome instead.

I have Android Webview installed and as far as I know it is a browser engine based on Chromium. I believe that apps that want to show web content use Android Webview for that. Am I right about this?

Is there a workaround to open a website using Webview without installing Google Chrome or other browser?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Android System Webview "app" (package com.google.android.webview) contains everything needed for displaying a web page.

But this app is designed to be used by other apps only so it does not has an own UI. The only activities it provides are for some sort of developer UI and a license dialog.

So you need at least a second app that shows a WebView to make use of Android System Webview app.

Answer (score -1):

Try Brave: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brave.browser
It's based on Chromium, it has all benefits of the Chrome browser.

Comment: While this might be a valid workaround, the question mentioned "*without installing Google Chrome or other browser*" though.